# Problem with installing tensorflow using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the error I got while trying to install tensorflow 2.2 using pip

```
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: pytest-astropy 0.8.0 requires pytest-cov>=2.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: pytest-astropy 0.8.0 requires pytest-filter-subpackage>=0.1, which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.3 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.3 has requirement wrapt==1.11.*, but you'll have wrapt 1.12.1 which is incompatible.

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\~umpy\\core\\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: I think it needs python version 3.0 and above. If you have python3 installed then try using pip3 command.

Comment: The error message suggests --user option. Did you try this? If you have the latest anaconda, Python3 should already be there. "pip install tensorflow --user" can fix the issue: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you do not have proper disk write permissions. You can try installing in in local user directory. Please try below command.
`pip install --user tensorflow`